# Applying fit transform to dataframe in python by using rpy2 to use princals in Gifi package of R

Tags: r, python-3.x, rpy2

I am trying to use the princals functionality of Gifi package of R, in python using rpy2. With my very short knowledge about R, I was able to do the fitting part of the function in my dataset.

Now I want to store the parameters so that I can use them to transform other similar data as well. However, I was unable to find the transform function in the fitted object.

```
    fitord = Gifi.princals(r_from_pd_df, ndim=2)
    object_scores = pandas2ri.ri2py_vector(fitord[3])
```

Now I want to be able to save the state for future use without fitting again. Also, are there any alternatives in python that can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

`rpy2` is making the Python objects wrapping R objects serializable using Python's "pickling". The doc is here:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_serialization.html

Comment: But my question is how we can use my fitord object to do the prediction on a new data set and not saving them for future use.